# How to generate a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to create a nested dictionary, like {'match':{'sam':65}, 'match':{'john':55}}.
When I run my code it generate the final dictionary as {'match':{'sam':55},{'john':65}}. How should I create a nested dictionary as discussed above?

following is my code:

```
        attribute = ['sam','john']
        value = [65,55]
        dict = {}
        main_dict = {}

        for j in range(len(attribute)):
            dict[attribute[j]] = value[j]

        for key, value in dict.items():
            main_dict['match'][key] = dict[key]
```

Comment: Neither of the two "dictionaries" in your first paragraph are valid Python dictionaries; your expected output is impossible because it has two of the same key, your "actual" output is impossible because it has a value not associated with any key.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot create dictionary with two same key.